# One-word synonym for "anonymous assistance"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a single noun or verb that means the following. The first on the list is the most important and the others are other characteristics the word must have.

1. **Anonymous assistance**
2. Rapid assistance
3. Getting assistance from someone with no regard to whoever it is

Comment: The kindness of strangers?

Comment: Possibly **(good) Samaritan**.

Comment: Why, please? Prolly the only words that might fit your actual question would be *beneficence* or *serendipity*.

However, in my view your three examples have nothing in common other than the word assistance, which they seem so disparate as to make irrelevant.

Comment: Why, please? Prolly the only words that might fit your actual question would be *beneficence* or *serendipity*. In my view your examples 1) and 3) are almost interchangeable but have nothing in common with the *rapid* in 2).